# How to detect that a text has been selected on Android browser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I would like to get an event, immediately after the user selected a text on Android Browser.

On a Windows Browser, I can use the `click` event with `addEventListener`. But this event will not be thrown on Android Chrome.

But there is a `selectionchange` event. This will be thrown on every change of the selection. But I would like to get the event, after the text was selected.

Comment: mouseup event? or equivalent touch event? I don't use android but the is no other selection event... maybe look into mouse up? or a timeout delay after no new selection changes?

Comment: @altruios: Yes "touchend" is the answer to my question. Now I'm happy!